# Display factors of a number in pairs

Tags: c++

Given a number n, the task is to print the factors of the number in such a way that they occur in pairs. A pair signifies that the product of the pair should result in the number itself;

```
for (int i = 1; i * i <= n; i++)
    if (n % i == 0)
        cout << i << "," << n / i << endl;
```

the code above works but I need the output to display the pair of factors from the middle.

Example:
The code above works like this

Enter a number: 68

1,68

2,34

4,17

But I need it to be like this

Enter a number: 68

4,17

2,34

1,68

Comment: I think the best way is to store the results in a ```std::vector``` and then display them from last to first

Comment: Or let the loop start from the middle: `for (int i = std::sqrt(n); i >= 0; --i)`.

Comment: sqrt(-68) wouldn't work though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply just reverse your search. To do this, you could just "swap" your *initialize* statement and you *test* statement in your for loop, and then decrement *i* instead of incrementing. The only thing with the piece of code you provided is that the i * i is a convenient way of finding the square root, so there would have to be used a square root function call instead.

```
for (int i = sqrt(n); i >= 1 ; i--)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start the search from the higher boundary and then go to the lower boundary. For example you can start the search from square root of the number and search toward reaching 1.

First use the `#include <math.h>` for the `sqrt` function(which calculates the square root). Then convert the square root of the number to integer by an `static_casrt`:

```
const int higher_bound = static_cast<int>(sqrt(n));
for (int i = higher_bound; i >=1 ; --i)
    if (n % i == 0)
        cout << i << "," << n / i << endl;
```